# angular2 webpack build error

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

this is code at gist,someone help?

https://gist.github.com/Dreampie/b58dd1152070ecf0f75a4e5fb7200615

> Error is :Cannot resolve module 'angular2/platform/browser'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resolve: {
  modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  extensions: ['', '.html', '.less', '.js', '.ts']
}
```

add `.js` to resolve

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you need to add the 'root' property to your resolve object: I use a helper function to return the root path seen in my [Angular2-Webpack-Lite boilerplate](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-webpack-lite/)

```
resolve: {
    root: root('src')
}
```

If this doesn't help, feel free to take a look at my boilerplate and see the rest of my configuration.